# A NullPointerException that seems impossible

Tags: android

I have the following code in a method. This is the entire method:

```
private boolean isPlaceEligible(String eligibleId) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String current = sharedPrefs.getString(
            PrefsActivity.AUTO_INELIGIBLE_ID, PrefsActivity.AUTO_INELIGIBLE_ID_DEF);
    return !eligibleId.equals(current);

}
```

eligibleId is known to be a non-null String. PrefsActivity.AUTO_INELIGIBLE_ID is a String key, and PrefsActivity.AUTO_INELIGIBLE_ID_DEF is a default String for that key.

The JavaDocs for those SharedPreferences don't say anything about returning null, but I've had some crash reports from the Market Console that say that this method is crashing on a NullPointerException. Based on the number of reports I got, I would estimate that this is happening to about one out of 300 users, maybe less. Two of them have emailed me about it and said that it happens 100% of the time.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you catching null reference before passing eligibleId to the method?

Comment: What line is actually throwing the NPE?

Comment: Any chance this is being called before the context on the Activity of which it is a member is initialized (before onCreate?)

Comment: Not catching it, but it passes through another method first that would certainly throw an NPE if it was null. I don't know what line throws it, only the method, from what I can tell from the trace. It's being called by a Service by a Handler's handleMessage() method. It gets its message in onStartCommand().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably the passed argument as the context in this line:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

This seems as the solution:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: Sounds promising. I haven't been able to reproduce the problem, so I'll have to release an app update and see how the customers respond. Thanks.

Comment: Hope you won't get them again. :)

Comment: They're still coming in. And they're getting pretty common. I had one of my customers clear his app data, and the problem went away permanently. There might be some kind of corruption in shared preferences going on.